# Sending e-mail on feature update in ArcGIS JavaScript application?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer

We have an ArcGIS feature service that users can edit to change a "project status" attribute.  An example would be a change from "pending" to "in-progress".  Certain groups need to be notified when that attributes new value impacts them.  For instance, a change to "in-progress" would let accounting know that charges may start coming in to the job.  I'd like to e-mail the appropriate parties using the user's default email client but I'm not sure how to handle the attribute change event.  I am new to the JavaScript API and at this point any information will be useful.  I've investigated the ArcGIS JavaScript API guide related to event handling but would benefit from a more specific example.

Comment: How can edits be made to the features - only via the web map application, or also via other mechanisms (desktop GIS, directly on the server, etc)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Edits will primarily be made from the web map application but I like the idea of having the office ArcMap users be able to edit.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your feature layer can only be edited via the ArcGIS Server JS API, you can attach a listener to the [edits-complete](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#event-edits-complete) event.

This will fire when the user makes any edit. You'll need to write the code to evaluate what to do at this point. For example, evaluate the edit, and if it has been a change from Pending to In Progress, then notify the relevant parties via email.

(A more robust approach would be to handle this at the database level, so that the trigger was fired regardless of how the edit was made, for example by an ArcMap user. You should post this as a new question if so, as it's beyond the scope of the ArcGIS Server JS API.)

Comment: I visited the edits-complete event but a link to sample for [FeatureEditResult](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featureeditresult-amd.html) is broken.
Please let me know if you have examples.
Thank you. Keisuke